# Javascript function not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to fire a function every 60 seconds.

Here is my current code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(alertme, 600000);
});  

function alertme() {
    alert('1 minute has passed');
} 
</script>
```

For some reason the function alertme is not being called.

Any ideas why?

Comment: It's not `600000` but **`60000`**.

Comment: thinking about actually waiting 10 min made me laugh.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interval parameter in the setInterval function is in milliseconds.

So 1 minute = 60 sec = 60 * 1000 millisec = 60000 millisec

Comment: You're giving what it should be, but you are forgetting to mention that it isn't what it currently is (with the only difference being the number of zeroes, it's easy to miss)

Answer (score 1):

There are 1,000ms in a second, not 10,000. This will fire after 10 minutes, not 1.

Answer (score 1):

60 seconds = 60000 ms not 600000

Answer (score 0):

600000 isn't one minute...

setInterval is in milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

Here is correct code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(alertme, 60000);
});  

function alertme() {
    alert('1 minute has passed');
} 
</script>
```